# hey i want my bot to show something like the the user you want to kick has higher role than you how can i do that?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, i want my bot to tell
that the user you want to kick has higher role than you

so is there any way to do this?

my python version - 3.10.0
my discord.py version - 2.0.0

any type of help will be appreciated!

So, i want my bot to tell
that the user you want to kick has higher role than you

so is there any way to do this?

my python version - 3.10.0
my discord.py version - 2.0.0

any type of help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you make it clearer? You want to tell `user` that who want to kick someone that has role higher than me?

Comment: yes you're right

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this is the right api but i believe you can just do something like

```
if role1 > role2:
```

and if the role is higher send the message to the user